# Adobe Muse: How to style body to 100% width?

Tags: css, muse

I've looked all over google and to be honest there aren't that many articles to answer a question as specific as this one , and i've tried going through the interface.
So when you make a new page , you have a body , and by default , that body has some margin's between it and the browser window , now i've managed to take care of the top and bottom one so there's no padding on the browser window ( a.k.a. margin's on the body ) but there's still space between the browser and the body on the left and the right side.

So how can i make my body's width be 100% of the browser's window because there's no width setting for the body , but only the page ( the browser window area).

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm a little new to Muse , so can you tell me how can i access the body's CSS or any element's CSS for that matter , in Muse?

Answer (score 1):

Okay here is the best I can do...

Aside from going to Page > Page properties > metadata and adding your own css file. what you can do is go to the rectangle tool and expand it to whatever height you want, however you MUST make sure that you expand the width to the edges of the web canvas past the body border until the tooltip displays 100%. afterwards embed whatever you want in there. but bewarned, the more complex the object the more custom coding you need to add.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to make an object 100% the width of a browser. It's not so obvious and it's hidden:

1. Draw a rectangular box and fill the box with photo (scale to fit), set color to none.
2. Resize the rectangular box to the same width of the canvas (page size).

The combination of the procedures above activates 100% width on the object.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are using "browser fill" and not just "fill". 
The fill one will fill in a box in the center.... 
Browser fill will literally fill the whole page. Got stuck on this for ages!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple one-click solution for 100% width, which I just came across in this awesome article after having trouble getting my footer to go all the way across on wide screen laptops...

In your top toolbar between the X/Y and W/H inuts, there is a little box with an arrow that points either way. Hover over it and you will see that it says '100%'.

click it and you're done!!! 
:-)

http://www.designeasy.co/2014/07/5-very-cool-tips-for-adobe-muse-cc-2014.html

Answer (score -1):

insert the following code into your header tags as follows                        (Where theme.css is the name of your css.)Now, go to you css and enter the css given to you by user255

Comment: The Muse website is on it's own server so if i want to see the page with 100% width i'd have to export it as HTML every time and then add the style file. Plus , isn't your solution too unpractical ? There should be a setting for this...

Answer (score -1):

Open your page in adobe muse Go to "Page properties" select "Metadata" From Page properties and add the following code to HTML for `<head>` area:

```css
<style>
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
</style>
```